# How to open Login-popup for Basic Auth when using jQuery-AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, basic-authentication

I use a jquery AJAX call to request a ressource which needs basic auth. Right now i'm doing it programmatically, and it works fine:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: record_app_uri,
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("admin" + ":" + "admin")},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (result) {
       //do something
    },
    error: function (result) {
    //do something
    }
});
```

Is it possible that the browser opens an login popup, like if i would access the *record_app_uri* directly with the browser:
[Screenshot Login-Popup form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUVzn.png)

**instead** of setting the Authorization-Header in the ajax-code like this:

```
headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("admin" + ":" + "admin")},
```

Comment: The password you are using can be seen by anyone using the site, change auth to server side code, or just don't use it. Right now, it's totally useless and insecure.

Comment: Hey @baao thanks for your response! First: I got your point. Right now everybody can see the username and password. My goal is not to have this data in jquery. Instead i want to enforce the user to login via a login popup (like i showed in the screenshot). In this case i wouldn't have to hardcode the login date into the jquery  script. Second: I know that basic auth itself is not secured, but i could use it in combination with HTTPS if i would need a secured transition. But right now, security is not an issue for me. I'm creating an application which is running in a protected network.